# Find maximum average using Dataframe API in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

I've got a table:

```
Country Emission
England 100
England 200
Germany 150
Germany 170
```

and I want to calculate average of Emission for every country and then find a country with the biggest average (something like `max(avg(Emission))`. **I would like to print the Country next to the calculated value**, like:
`Germany 160`.

I know that I can do it by calculating `avg`, sorting by `avg` and then print the first row, but sorting seems to be suboptimal. Can I ommit this?

This is the solution with sorting which I wrote:

```py
spdf\
    .groupBy("Country")\
    .agg(f.avg("Emission").alias("Emission"))\
    .orderBy(f.desc("Emission"))\
    .limit(1)\
    .show()
```

and this is the query, which returns only `max(avg(Emission))`

```py
spdf\
    .groupBy("Country")\
    .avg("Emission")\
    .agg(f.max("avg(Emission)").alias("Emission"))\
    .show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that it is a shame to sort something just to get the maximum value. Therefore, what you can do is use the `max` function. Since you want to keep the name of the country and not just the maximum value of Emission, you can bind the two column together in a `struct`. The code would look like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
data=[("England", 100), ("England", 200), ("Germany", 150), ("Germany", 170)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Country", "Emission"])

df.groupBy("Country")\
  .agg(F.avg("Emission").alias("Emission"))\
  .select(F.max(F.struct("Emission", "Country")).alias("s"))\
  .select("s.*")\
  .show()
```

```
+--------+-------+
|Emission|Country|
+--------+-------+
|   160.0|Germany|
+--------+-------+
```

The first `select` selects the country with maximum Emission. The result is wrapped within a struct named `"s"`. The second select unwraps the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use window function instead of group by. The idea is also to construct a struct, get the maximum of that struct and expand its elements.

```
df2 = df.selectExpr('struct(Country, avg(Emission) over (partition by Country) avg_emission) s') \
        .selectExpr('max(s) s') \
        .select('s.*')

df2.show()
+-------+------------+
|Country|avg_emission|
+-------+------------+
|Germany|       160.0|
+-------+------------+
```